# 11ty render single post per data file

Tags: eleventy

I want 11ty to generate a single page per data file, rather than generate multiple files by iterating over the data within a data file. Is this possible?

My use case is that I have multiple job descriptions in `yaml` format: One yaml page per job. So I want to generate a page for each data file.

I realise I could put all the yaml data as front matter in a page with no content, but this feel wrong as I only have the data.

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use [collections](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/collections/) combined with [pagination](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/pagination/) to create one output file per job. The key is using a pagination size of 1, this way you only need one page in your site directory, and it will create one output page per job. This is documented in [Create Pages From Data](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/pages-from-data/).

The example in the linked documentation article uses one data file (`possums.json`) and paginates over the object that eleventy generates for that file. If you have one data file per element (job, in your case), you can achieve the same thing by putting all those datafiles inside a parent directory inside the _data directory, and iterate over that. The key here is understanding how eleventy handles [nested directories in the global data directory](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-global/#folders) and that you can [use pagination with an object](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/pagination/#paging-an-object).

So if you have your yaml job files structured like this:

- `_data/jobs/job1.yaml`
- `_data/jobs/job2.yaml`
- `_data/jobs/job3.yaml`

You should be able to paginate them like this (adapted from the example in the documentation, might have to adjust a bit to make it work with your content):

```
pagination:
    data: jobs
    size: 1
    alias: job
    resolve: values
permalink: "jobs/{{ job.name | slug }}/"
```

Comment: Thanks @MoritzLost. So I want one template to be used for multiple data files.
I think collections and pagination is for using one template for one data file.
So if I have data files: jd1,yaml, jd2.yaml, jd3.yaml
To use pagination, I believe I'd need a template per yaml file. 
I only want to use the one template file though.
Could you provide some code examples of how you think it will work? I've been referring to the docs, and I can't see how

Comment: @pat I've added an example. The key is to put all your job data files in a sub-directory and than use the name of the subdirectory for the pagination. Not sure if the example will work out of the box (can't test right now), but if you read the two additional doc pages I linked above you should be able to make it work with one template file.

Comment: Hey that worked first time. Really simple.
Thanks so much for explaining in more detail.

Comment: Also vredeburg theme uses this trick for the category pagination. You can check out a working sample there.

Comment: `resolve: values` was the piece I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it feels just right :) drop that files into it and get your pages done in a seconds. If all you need is to convert them to pages it's a fastest way.
Collections will give you listings and so on.